# How to get values from a list which is generated by "new map()" HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, hql

This is my HQL.

```
List<Map<Long, String>> list = getSession().createQuery("select new map(id, fname) from Employee").list();
```

When I print the list variable on console, I get

```
{1=Kevin, 0=5}, {1=Louis, 0=8}, {1=Micheal, 0=15}
```

I just want to know how to iterate the above list and how to get values from the list.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the types involved it'll be something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : List) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey());
  System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

**Update**

Based on the new sample the answer is this:

```
for (Map<Long, String> map : list) {
  for (Entry<Long, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: What do I do if I know the types?

See the sample code.

`code` List<Map<Long, String>> list = getSession().createQuery("select new map(id, fname) from Employee").list();

Comment: That sample code is different than the original. I updated your question and my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I think "for (Entry<Long, String>.." is wrong., it must be for (Map.Entry<Long, String>.. Right?

And still, I am getting exception something like this, Hibernate: select employee0_.id as col_0_0_, employee0_.fname as col_1_0_ from hba.employees employee0_
1
Praveen
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at test.HibernateMap.main(HibernateMap.java:14)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Deepesh, you can use either `Map.Entry` or `Entry` with a [static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) `import static java.util.Map.Entry;`. If what you get is a map with strings instead of long/string as in your code snippet you have to make that `List<Map<String, String>>` of course.

Comment: I agree with you. It's ok, but just look into my list. It's of the form **list: [{1=Praveen, 0=1}, {1=Deepesh, 0=4}, {1=Kevin, 0=5}, {1=Louis, 0=8}, {1=Micheal, 0=15}, {1=Robin, 0=27}, {1=Ram, 0=33}, {1=Tom, 0=41}, {1=Prem, 0=53}]**.

Then how can I Iterate with Entry? What I did is ` for (Map<Long, String> map : list) {
            for (Entry<Long, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        }`

Comment: Since `0=1`(**{1=Praveen, 0=1}**), and 1 is a long value(in my entity), I again get an exception, this is what i got 

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
**

Comment: This is my full snippet

`import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class HibernateMap extends DAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, String>> list = getSession().createQuery("select new map(id, fname) from Employee").list();
        System.out.println("list: " + list);
        for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: @Deepesh, what is the super class of both `String` and `Long`? Right, it's `Object`. Apparently some piece of code does type conversion. So, for one entry the value seems to be a `String` (`1=Praveen`) while for others the value appears to be a `Long` (`0=1`). Not sure if you get it back like this or if the JVM does this because of your generics declaration. That's my assumption based on the exception you posted. Since you don't tell us on which line you get the `ClassCastException` I'm not quite sure which option is best. You can try with `List<Map<Object, Object>>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine for me. I've changed my code to `for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            }` and it works. But I have one more doubt, I got the output from the above code is **Praveen
1
Deepesh
4
Kevin
5
Louis
8
Micheal
15
Robin
27
Ram
33
Tom
41
Prem
53**

When I print `entry.getValue()`, I get both _id_ and _name_. My doubt is, how to extract _ids_ or _names_ alone?

Comment: @Deepesh, with `System.out.println(entry.getValue())` and the value being an `Object` Java automatically invokes the object's `toString()` method. You need to go from there... find out what the real type is by debugging or `entry.getClass().getName()` then you need to check its `toString()` and develop your program further.

Comment: Thanks. The class type it shows is **java.util.HashMap$Entry**